# How to remove boost installed on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boost, ubuntu-18.04

I have removed Boost by command. and in version.hpp it showed 1.65.1

sudo apt-get --purge remove libboost-all-dev

But with that i have boost 1.75 version

my question is how to remove 1.75 version.

Answer (score 1):

do in the command line:

```
 libboost1.75-dev
```

and after that

```
sudo apt-get autoremove <package>
```

Comment: no its giving as..........................Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libboost1.75
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libboost1.75'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libboost1.75'

Comment: dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version' ........  This command line is giving as version 1.65.1 .............. but my " cmake " .. command is using boost 1.75... i want to use 1.65.1 .... but NOT 1.75..... Any help can be appreciated